# Keeping the value of control variable same after iteration - Why isn't it working?

Tags: java

[[image: Works fine with [3,2,1] and [1,2,3] but for the example in the image, it keeps on running.[1]]

In the second for loop I need to keep the value of 's' same if the if statement is true. So, I decreased the value of 's', so that when it is incremented in the next step, it remains same. But it doesn't work. Why?

I give two arrays, say 3,2,1 and 1,2,3. I need to change the first array to second and calculate time needed. This I do by checking the first element. If same, then move to the next, else push the first element to the end, and the rest of the elements to one position above and repeat the process. Every time I push an element to the end I increment the value of 'time'.

The code works fine with [3,2,1] and [1,2,3], but when it comes to the example in the image it keeps on running.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Monkon {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the number of test cases");
      int t = Integer.parseInt(scn.nextLine());
      int[][] p = new int[t][2];
      int[] a = new int[t];
      int[] b = new int[t];
      int time = 0;
      for (int s = 1; s <= t; s++) {
         a[s - 1] = p[s - 1][0] = scn.nextInt();
         b[s - 1] = p[s - 1][1] = scn.nextInt();
      }
      for (int s = 1; s <= t; s++) {
         int c = a[s - 1];
         if (b[s - 1] != a[s - 1]) {
            for (int y = s; y < t; y++) {
               a[y - 1] = a[y];
            }
            a[t - 1] = c;
            time++;
            s = s - 1;
         } else
            time++;
      }
      System.out.println(time);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please look up and try to follow Java code formatting rules. By following these rules, others will more easily be able to read and understand your code, and then be able to help you. If you are using most IDE's they can help you format your code correctly for you. Edit: I've tried to fix your code's formatting, but in the future, this should be your responsibility, since you're the one seeking free advice from the volunteers who help here.

Comment: I am extremely sorry. I overlooked the preview section this one time

Comment: what do you mean by it's not working?

Comment: Can you explain your question in more detail? Especially "value of 's' same if the if statement is true.".

Comment: @karthik, It isn't returning anything

Comment: @karthik, Since I am changing the array, why does it go into an infinite loop?

Comment: @EnochKattumuri yeah, I just realized that, but can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? This seems very convoluted.

Comment: @EnochKattumuri Is p intended to contain all of the elements of a and b?  If it is, I'm guessing you meant to set b[s-1] = p[s-1][1] = scn.nextInt().

Comment: @user2791611 I have changed it. yet it isn't working. Thanks for notifiying

Comment: @Enoch that's the fundamental mistake you are doing. Your input will be read as `{3,1,3}` `{2,1,2}`. To capture `{3,2,1}` &  `{1,3,2}` you have to give the input sequence `{3,1,2,3,1,2}`  That is what I explained in my answer.  Read it again

Comment: @karthik What changes do I need to make so that I can give the input straight forward?

Comment: @EnochKattumuri I have added that to the end of my answer, check that. You need to change the way you are reading the input. Once you change it, you can give the input normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is, it will go in to infinite loop if you can not convert your 1st array in to the second array by the operation you have defined and that is the problem you are facing.

If you consider your example like `{3,2,1}` and `{1,2,3}` it terminates well and gives output.

If you give array like `{1,2,3}` and `{1,2,4}` it will go in to infinite loop as it is not possible convert first array into second array by any number of operations.

I think you are  also reading the input incorrectly. I ran your program and you can see a screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF5si.png).

In the input `{3,3,1,2,3,1,2}` the first `3` is the input for number of elements (test cases in your program terminology).

In the remaining input alternate numbers will go into same array, because you are reading the input like

```
 a[s - 1] = p[s - 1][0] = scn.nextInt();
 b[s - 1] = p[s - 1][1] = scn.nextInt();
```

in the remaining {**3**,1,**2**,3,**1**,2}, the numbers which are bold will go in to first array - `{3,1,2}` and the other numbers will go in to second array - `{1,3,2}`.

This input gives `5` as answer.

**UPDATE**

To keep the things simple, I suggest you to replace

```
for (int s = 1; s <= t; s++) {
     a[s - 1] = p[s - 1][0] = scn.nextInt();
     b[s - 1] = p[s - 1][1] = scn.nextInt();
}
```

with

```
 for (int s = 1; s <= t; s++) {
     a[s - 1] = p[s - 1][0] = scn.nextInt();
  }
  for (int s = 1; s <= t; s++) {
     b[s - 1] = p[s - 1][1] = scn.nextInt();
  }
```

Comment: But then it isn't even working for the above example of {3,2,1} and {1,2,3}

Comment: It works for me.  The way that you're capturing the input is a little convoluted; are you sure that it's actually capturing {3, 2, 1} and {1, 2, 3} for a and b?

Comment: @EnochKattumuri I just ran your program for `{3,2,1}`  and `{1,2,3}` and it outputs `6`

Comment: @karthik Try {3,2,1} and { 1,3,2}

Comment: @EnochKattumuri Yes, it works for that input too. http://i.stack.imgur.com/fF5si.png

I think you are reading the input incorrectly. check the  screenshot I attached and the input sequence in that.

Comment: @karthik Isn't the input sequence [3,2,1] and [3,2,1] in that screenshot. By the way change b[s-1] = p[s-1][0] to b[s-1] = p[s-1][1]

Comment: @EnochKattumuri no, it's `{3,2,1}` and `{1,3,2}`. I have edited the answer and explained it.

Comment: Yep, So I have seen. Now what do you think is wrong when I run the same  code. How do I attach a scrrenshot? Just to show how my editor is executing it

Comment: Did you give the input sequence just like I have given? Edit your question and attach screen shot in the question.

https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/